# DataTable in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, datatable

I hava a dataTable in a jsf, how can i get all the values from that table.

Here is my table:

```
<h:dataTable id="dt1" value="#{Metadata.placeholders}" var="item" binding="#{Metadata.dataTable}" bgcolor="#F1F1F1" border="10" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="3" first="0" rows="4" width="40%" frame="hsides" rules="all" summary="This is a JSF code to create dataTable." >

                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Select elements for available placeholder" />
                    </f:facet> 

                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Placeholder" />
                        </f:facet> 
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.id}"/>
                    </h:column>

                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Element"/>
                        </f:facet> 
                        <h:selectOneListbox id="elements" size="1" >
                            <f:selectItems value="#{item.elements}" /> 
                        </h:selectOneListbox>
                    </h:column>

                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Value"/>
                        </f:facet> 
                        <h:inputText></h:inputText> 
                    </h:column>

                </h:dataTable><br>
```

As you can see, the second and third column are listbox and input text felds, so let assume that the table has 5 rows and the user select a value form the listbox and input a text in the text field, so how can i get that data after the user press "submit" button?

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988869/how-can-i-get-values-out-of-a-selectonemenu-inside-a-jsf-datatable

Comment: Yes, i saw this post, but it's does not work for me. List<String> selectedRowData = (List<String>) getDataTable().getRowData()
this peace of code throw exception, and as far as i see getRowData() method return an object for a current selected row...

Comment: And how do you implement the getDataTable() method? It should return DataModel, which you can obtain from FacesContext.

Comment: I don't, i the backed bean i have  "private HtmlDataTable dataTable;" where dataTable is bind in the jsf. So after i call getDataTable().getRowData()  it returns only one row.. not all the records in the table as it's in the API.

Comment: I looked in the javadoc and is says this: "Return an object representing the data for the currenty selected row index.". So I guess it returns only one row. If you want the whole table, just iterate over it and select the rows continuously.

Comment: That's my questio :)) How to do it. the iteration...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just bind the dropdown value to a property of the currently iterated item.

```html
<h:dataTable value="#{metadata.placeholders}" var="placeholder">
    <h:column>
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{placeholder.element}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{placeholder.elements}" /> 
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
<h:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{metadata.submit}" />
```

*(note that I fixed the nonsensicial `<h:selectOneListbox size="1">` by a `<h:selectOneMenu>`)*

When you submit the form, JSF will just set the value in the `element` property of the iterated `Placeholder` object. If you intend to access it individually just loop over `placeholders` in the action method.

```
public void submit() {
    for (Placeholder placeholder : placeholders) {
        System.out.println(placeholder.getElement()); // Look, JSF has already set it.
    }
}
```

Comment: @BalusC, I swear I've learned more about JSF here from you in StackOverlow than I have from the official documentation.  Thanks for sharing/participating.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a sample code, but the idea should be in there

```
for (int i = 0; i < getDataTable().getRowCount(); i++) {
    getDataTable().setRowIndex(i);
    Object object = getDataTable().getRowData();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Listbox and your Inputtext does not know where (and how) to store their values. 
So JSF usualy have managed-bean's and converter's and map the values via value-attribute.

If you are not sure whats the name of the properties, you can inherit two hashmaps to pass the values.
eg:

```
< ... value="#{Metadata.placeholderMap[item.id]['age']}" ... >
```